# What are the proper steps to change container registry storage location for Gitlab-CE?

Tags: docker-registry, gitlab-ce

I have installed Gitlab-CE on a small server ([ZimaBoard](https://www.zimaboard.com/)). I host all code on Gitlab, run a gitlab-runner on one Zima, and host the images on the other ZimaBoard. The default storage location is limited, so I have added an external SSD and mount it in fstab. From what I can find [here](https://spirasystems.ddns.net:8085/help/administration/packages/container_registry#configure-storage-for-the-container-registry). Claims the only change in configuration should be, changing the default location to the location you want.

```
# Change this:
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"
# To this:
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/path/to/registry/storage"
```

So I do that and run reconfigure. However, when I try to login to the registry, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://<my_url>:5050/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

If I change it back to the default, I have no issues logging in. Where should I start to resolve this issue? Is this possibly a permissions issue on my external drive?

Followed Gitlab documentation to change registry storage location.
Expected all new images pushed to registry to be stored in updated location.
The registry is no longer accessible after updated the primary storage location.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions issue with the drive. When you run reconfigure, it changes the permissions on the directory you specify. Make sure to add the user to the appropriate groups, or just a heavy hand like me:

```bash
chmod -R 777 <target>
```